# Cocos2d, CCMenuSprite, Scaling and Positioning Issue

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, positioning, scale

I can't figure out how to correctly position in the scene some menu buttons created with scaled sprites.

If I create the sprites, scale them, and set their position, it all goes fine.

If I create the sprites, scale them, set their position and then use them to create the CCMenuItemSprite they are all shifted left and down.

If I crete the sprites, use them to create the CCMenuItemSprite, scale the menu item and set the menu items position, they are all shifted right and up.

All those settings are done with the same scale factor and center point coordinates of course.

What am I missing??

Thanks!

EDIT: SOLVED!!

I got it figured out!! It was all due to how the coordinate system of the menu works and how it reacts when the menu is scaled.

I don't know right now it I was taking a non correct approach to the problem, which is very possible, or if there is something tricky in how all the system is thought.

I will dig into it an write a little tutorial ASAP.

Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I just wanted to share what happened to me here (I hope it is helpful). I just had the same problem described in this question and as @mokagio said above the problem is with how the coodinate system of the menu works.

First I created a Sprite and a MenuItemSprite with it, but I could never position them correctly. Then I realised that I should do all the scaling and positioning based on the MenuItemSprite and not in the Sprite and everything worked fine!

The code I used was:

```
CCPoint backButtonPosition;
CCSprite *backButtonSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("Back.png");
CCMenuItemSprite *backButton = CCMenuItemSprite::create(backButtonSprite, backButtonSprite, this, menu_selector(MyMenuClass::buttonPressedCallback));

// Do all the scaling and positioning using the CCMenuItemSprite and not the CCSprite
backButton->setScale(0.5);
backButtonPosition = ccp(backButton->boundingBox().size.width / 2, screenSize.height - backButton->boundingBox().size.height / 2);

// Position the button, but first convert the world coordinates to the parent menu local coordinates
backButton->setPosition(categorySelectMenu->convertToNodeSpace(backButtonPosition));
categorySelectMenu->addChild(backButton);
```

Also, please note that it is important to set the button position according to the menu coordinate system and not to the world coordinate system.